# How to change the style of the title attribute inside an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

Example:

```
<a href="example.com" title="My site"> Link </a>
```

How do I change the presentation of the "title" attribute in the browser?. By default, it just has yellow background and small font. I would like to make it bigger and change the background color.

Is there a CSS way to style the title attribute?

Comment: I've made a tiny script which does that called [title-tooltips](https://github.com/yairEO/title-tooltip)

Answer (score 212):

It seems that there is in fact a pure CSS solution, requiring only the css `attr` expression, generated content and attribute selectors (which suggests that it works as far back as IE8):

https://jsfiddle.net/z42r2vv0/2/

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a[title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/" title="Hello world!">
  Hover over me
</a>
```

**update** w/ input from @ViROscar: please note that it's not necessary to use any specific attribute, although I've used the "title" attribute in the example above; actually my recommendation would be to use the "alt" attribute, as there is some chance that the content will be accessible to users unable to benefit from CSS.

**update again** I'm not changing the code because the "title" attribute has basically come to mean the "tooltip" attribute, and it's probably not a good idea to hide important text inside a field only accessible on hover, but if you're interested in making this text accessible the "aria-label" attribute seems like the best place for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

Comment: And if you do not wish for the native tooltip to eventually display as well, you can always use the "alt" tag..

Comment: @Jonz i've tried with a custom property "data-alt='alt'" and everything goes ok. is not necessary to use the alt or title property.

Comment: Pure CSS Tooltips has serious wrawback -- they are bounded to the element, thus bounded to its [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). All elements with `position` other than `static` creates new *stacking context* and pure CSS tooltips are not visible outside nor can go beyond such *stacking context*, so if you have tight element with position `relative`, your CSS tooltip will not be visible. The only solution is attaching tooltip to top *stacking context* (e.g. `<body>`) which needs JavaScript.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't disappear on click.

Comment: I know this is a really old reply, but this is the only one I've found that is really useful. I recommend using aria-label instad of alt or title as it costs nothing and it will help people with acessibility..

Comment: I would use a HTML data attribute e.g. data-tooltip

a[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
}

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The title attribute seems to be handled by the browser, at least for Chrome, and can't be styled.

Comment: But this shows both tool tips. The default as well as the custom

Answer (score 204):

## You can't style an actual `title` attribute

How the text in the `title` attribute is displayed is defined by the browser and varies from browser to browser. It's not possible for a webpage to apply any style to the tooltip that the browser displays based on the `title` attribute.

However, you can create something very similar using other attributes.

## You can make a pseudo-tooltip with CSS and a custom attribute (e.g. `data-title`)

For this, I'd use a `data-title` attribute. [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) are a method to store custom data in DOM elements/HTML. There are [multiple ways of accessing them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Importantly, they can be selected by CSS.

Given that you can use CSS to select elements with `data-title` attributes, you can then use CSS to create [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) (or [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)) [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) that contains the value of the attribute using [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

### Styled tooltip Examples

**Bigger and with a different background color (per question's request):**

```css
[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}
[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    background-color: #00FF00;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    bottom: -1.6em;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
}
[data-title] {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com" data-title="My site"> Link </a> with styled tooltip (bigger and with a different background color, as requested in the question)<br/>
<a href="example.com" title="My site"> Link </a> with normal tooltip
```

**More elaborate styling (adapted from [this blog post](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/)):**

```css
[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}
[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1.6em;
    left: 100%;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 8px;
    color: #222;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
    border-radius: 5px;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;  
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #f8f8f8),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);  
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
}
[data-title] {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com" data-title="My site"> Link </a> with styled tooltip<br/>
<a href="example.com" title="My site"> Link </a> with normal tooltip
```

### Known issues

Unlike a real `title` tooltip, the tooltip produced by the above CSS is not, necessarily, guaranteed to be visible on the page (i.e. it might be outside the visible area). On the other hand, it is guaranteed to be within the current window, which is not the case for an actual tooltip.

In addition, the pseudo-tooltip is positioned relative to the element that has the pseudo-tooltip rather than relative to where the mouse is on that element. You may want to fine-tune where the pseudo-tooltip is displayed. Having it appear in a known location relative to the element can be a benefit or a drawback, depending on the situation.

#### You can't use `:before` or `:after` on elements which are not containers

There's a good explanation in [this answer to "Can I use a :before or :after pseudo-element on an input field?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/3773011)

Effectively, this means that you can't use this method directly on elements like `<input type="text"/>`, `<textarea/>`, `<img>`, etc. The easy solution is to wrap the element that's not a container in a `<span>` or `<div>` and have the pseudo-tooltip on the container.

**Examples of using a pseudo-tooltip on a `<span>` wrapping a non-container element:**

```css
[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}
[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    background-color: #00FF00;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    bottom: -1.6em;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
}
[data-title] {
    position: relative;
}

.pseudo-tooltip-wrapper {
    /*This causes the wrapping element to be the same size as what it contains.*/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
Text input with a pseudo-tooltip:<br/>
<span class="pseudo-tooltip-wrapper" data-title="input type=&quot;text&quot;"><input type='text'></span><br/><br/><br/>
Textarea with a pseudo-tooltip:<br/>
<span class="pseudo-tooltip-wrapper" data-title="this is a textarea"><textarea data-title="this is a textarea"></textarea></span><br/>
```

---

<sup>From the code on the blog post linked above (which I first saw in an answer here that plagiarized it), it appeared obvious to me to use a `data-*` attribute instead of the `title` attribute. Doing so was also suggested in a comment by [snostorm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287750/snostorm) on that (now deleted) answer.</sup>

Comment: This may not the answer to the  question, but this is the best solution so far. Thanks.

Comment: @JJLabajo Thanks for the complement about this being the best solution so far. However, I'm not sure how this doesn't answer the question. The question is asking for something that's just not possible. This answer says it's not possible, but offers an alternative that accomplishes something similar to what the OP desires while complying with the requirement in the question that it be a CSS-based solution. If you want to use additional HTML and/or JavaScript, you can have much more elaborate displays that appear upon hover.

Comment: I think this solution does not apply to elements like `input[type='text']` or `textarea`, but I don't know why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @Cheeso You're correct, the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements don't work on elements which are not containers. There's a good explanation in the answer: [Can I use a :before or :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434) To use this method, it is probably easiest to wrap the elements which are not containers in a `<span>` or `<div>` on which you put the `data-title` attribute. You'll probably also want to give them `display: inline-block;`, as that will make them the same size as the `<input>` or `<textarea>`. I've updated this answer with an example.

Comment: This answer actually teaches us what's going on and provides all kinds of well-structured background information.

Comment: Suppose if we use required for  input attribute we will get two title, one is the default one and another one is the customized one. how to hide the default one: '<span class="pseudo-tooltip-wrapper" data-title="input type=&quot;text&quot;"><input type='text' required=true></span><br/><br/><br/>'
Textarea with a pseudo-tooltip:<br/>' @Makyen

Comment: @AVINASHM, If you do something that causes a browser defined tooltip to appear, there's nothing you can do to prevent that from happening, other than to not do the thing which causes that tooltip to appear. In the specific case of using `required=true`, you will need to not use that attribute and implement your own validation for the form. Alternately, you can cause the pseudo tooltip to appear at a location which will not be occupied by the default tooltip. Where that could be will be browser specific, but you could implement CSS which covers the browsers you're interested in supporting.

Comment: Other possibilities for using `required=true` are A) have JavaScript code that temporarily removes the `required` attribute whenever the mouse is hovered over an input element and then replaces it once the mouse moves out of the element. B) probably better: have JavaScript that moves all `required` attributes into something like `data-required` until the form is in the process of being submitted, then restore those attributes to `required` while the `submit` is occurring. After the submit and its verification is complete, then put them back to `data-required`.

Comment: Do we have any code snippet related to this for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pa2lnu @Makyen

Comment: @AVINASHM I don't, currently, have any code that does either of the solutions I mentioned above. However, it shouldn't be that difficult to write something which accomplishes either of the two JavaScript possibilities I mentioned.

Comment: The solution is good, but..
The tooltip is displayed on one line. If the tooltip text is 100-150 characters, then without wrapping the line it does not look beautiful.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rw1tnxa/)

Comment: @Arsen I'm not sure why you have an issue. Obviously, you'd adjust the CSS such that the tooltip would look good in the context in which you are using it. What's used here was intended only as a proof of concept and to implement the specific formatting requested in the question. If you want the words to wrap, it's trivial to remove the `white-space: nowrap;` and apply other CSS properties (e.g. `width`, `height`, `max-width`, `max-height`, etc.). The actual CSS used wasn't intended as the end-all be-all for all situations, but only to demonstrate a way to accomplish the requested task.

Comment: @Arsen If you need more intricate formatting than what's possible with this, there are more complex options for tooltip-like displays (i.e. that appear on hover). However, those require more significant HTML changes and/or JavaScript, which are outside what was asked for in this question, which asks for a CSS solution "to make it bigger and change the background color." For example, I use an HTML and CSS solution to produce [this tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhVZf.png) for my [Roomba Forecaster](//stackapps.com/questions/7239) userscript.

Comment: Yes, the concept is clear. CSS issue. The wrapper should be the width of the characters. And limited to the max-width parameter. [Sample](http://s25.znimg.ru/1580758560/xozup5mvnt.png). Removing white-space does not help. What needs to be changed to get it like on a sample?

Comment: Any quick tip for hiding blank rows where this logic might be used in a table? I could use PHP but curious if CSS solution for blank values.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not really sure what you're asking. I have a few guesses as to what you mean, but how to solve it really depends on the situation you're working with. The long and short of it is that what I *think* you're asking about really deserves it's [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), so you can fully describe the issue you're dealing with, and so you can get input/answers from multiple people.

Comment: @Makyen, I was asking if you implement this on hover over a table cell, how to prevent if that cell is blank. I solved via PHP: $notes = trim($row['notes']); $data_title = ' data-title="' . $notes . '" '; . . . and then in the rows for the <td> attribute: echo strlen($notes)>0 ? $data_title : ''; and that worked great.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It provides very clear solutions. I have accomplished my goal of learning something new today:)

Comment: It will be responsive or not?

Comment: @MhkAsif That's going to depend on the CSS styling you use on the `:after` or `:before` and the containing elements, so isn't really answerable, as it being responsive is up to you and how you define and implement responsiveness in your page.

Comment: This appears to work okay with A elements, even if they are positioned.

Comment: @DavidSpector RE: your edit suggestion: I'm unsure if the issue you're attempting to resolve is global. Adding `z-index:-1` to the `[data-title]`, on first glance, appears to be more specific to within your implementation, rather than a global issue. Using any `position` value along with a `z-index` which isn't `auto` forms a new stacking context, which may be needed, depending on how things are within the page. I'd appreciate it if you could provide an example, perhaps on [jsfiddle](//jsfiddle.net), of the issue you're trying to address, so I can get a better feel for if it's a global issue.

Comment: I assume this is NOT accessibility friendly? I thought about adding tooltip text to both title and the custom attribute, but then I'd get battling tooltips

Answer (score 148):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```css
a.tip {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    text-decoration: none
}
a.tip:hover {
    cursor: help;
    position: relative
}
a.tip span {
    display: none
}
a.tip:hover span {
    border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    background: url(../images/status-info.png) #f0f0f0 no-repeat 100% 5%;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tip">Link<span>This is the CSS tooltip showing up when you mouse over the link</span></a>
```

Comment: doesn't work properly in FF if instead of the tag **a** use the tag, for instance, **td**

Comment: See http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/ for an example of the above technique, with a detailed explanation.

Comment: When I do this, I see a double tool tip. The styled one, and then shortly after, the unstyled one pops over this one. This is on your fiddle. I am using chrome. Is this an abnormality?

Comment: An answer without the title attribute in the code has over 100 upvotes here...?

Comment: Doesn't even address the actual question...boo!

Comment: If it's going to be done like this, it needs a transition with a delay. Display is none transitionable but I think an opacity or sizing change would be fine. It depends on the use case but instant tooltips can be annoying especially if you have lots that appear over other elements

Comment: If one  has to deal with a overflows for the provided solution, one can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718020/325868

Answer (score 31):

CSS can't change the tooltip appearance. It is browser/OS-dependent. If you want something different you'll have to use Javascript to generate markup when you hover over the element instead of the default tooltip.

Comment: One doesn't *have* to use JS to do it.

Comment: The risk with 'you can't' answers is that they can become out-of-date. (The other risk is that you could just not know how.)

Answer (score 28):

I have found the answer here: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

my own code goes like this, I have changed the attribute name, if you maintain the title name for the attribute you end up having two popups for the same text, another change is that my text on hovering displays underneath the exposed text.

```css
.tags {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.tags:hover:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: -34px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-gloss);
  left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 350px;
}

.tags:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  bottom: -4px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<a class="tags" data-gloss="Text shown on hovering">Exposed text</a>
```

Comment: gloss won't be HTML valid. `data-gloss` would.

Answer (score 12):

I thought i'd post my 20 lines JavaScript solution here. It is not perfect, but may be useful for some depending on what you need from your tooltips.

**When to use it**

- Automatically styles the tooltip for all HTML elements with a `TITLE` attribute defined (this includes elements dynamically added to the document in the future)
- No Javascript/HTML changes or hacks required for every tooltip (just the `TITLE` attribute, semantically clear)
- Very light (adds about 300 bytes gzipped and minified)
- You want only a very basic styleable tooltip

**When NOT to use**

- Requires jQuery, so do not use if you don't use jQuery
- Bad support for nested elements that both have tooltips
- You need more than one tooltip on the screen at the same time
- You need the tooltip to disappear after some time

**The code**

```
// Use a closure to keep vars out of global scope
(function () {
    var ID = "tooltip", CLS_ON = "tooltip_ON", FOLLOW = true,
    DATA = "_tooltip", OFFSET_X = 20, OFFSET_Y = 10,
    showAt = function (e) {
        var ntop = e.pageY + OFFSET_Y, nleft = e.pageX + OFFSET_X;
        $("#" + ID).html($(e.target).data(DATA)).css({
            position: "absolute", top: ntop, left: nleft
        }).show();
    };
    $(document).on("mouseenter", "*[title]", function (e) {
        $(this).data(DATA, $(this).attr("title"));
        $(this).removeAttr("title").addClass(CLS_ON);
        $("<div id='" + ID + "' />").appendTo("body");
        showAt(e);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "." + CLS_ON, function (e) {
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).data(DATA)).removeClass(CLS_ON);
        $("#" + ID).remove();
    });
    if (FOLLOW) { $(document).on("mousemove", "." + CLS_ON, showAt); }
}());
```

Paste it anywhere, it should work even when you run this code before the DOM is ready (it just won't show your tooltips until DOM is ready).

**Customize**

You can change the `var` declarations on the second line to customize it a bit.

```
var ID = "tooltip"; // The ID of the styleable tooltip
var CLS_ON = "tooltip_ON"; // Does not matter, make it somewhat unique
var FOLLOW = true; // TRUE to enable mouse following, FALSE to have static tooltips
var DATA = "_tooltip"; // Does not matter, make it somewhat unique
var OFFSET_X = 20, OFFSET_Y = 10; // Tooltip's distance to the cursor
```

**Style**

You can now style your tooltips using the following CSS:

```
#tooltip {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Fix for a minor bug (if title is empty) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702472/bug-fix-for-a-script-that-applies-css-to-the-title-attribute

Comment: If you move rapidly over an element I am getting an empty tooltip, even with the bug fix mentioned above. This is erratic and stops if I take off the $(this).removeAttr("title"). But of course I then get the standard help showing after a while.

Answer (score 8):

A jsfiddle for custom tooltip pattern is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/prasun_sultania/KSk42/)

It is based on CSS Positioning and pseduo class selectors

Check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) for cross-browser support of pseudo classes

```
    <!-- HTML -->
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="tooltip">
    I am a 
        <span> (This website rocks) </span></a>&nbsp; a developer.
</p>

    /*CSS*/
a.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}

a.tooltip span {
    display: none;    
}

a.tooltip:hover span, a.tooltip:focus span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:1em;
    left:1.5em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border:1px solid #996633;
    background-color:#FFFF66;
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Native tooltip cannot be styled.

That being said, you can use some library that would show styles floating layers when element is being hovered (instead of the native tooltips, and suppress them) requiring little or no code modifications...

Comment: I don’t think you can suppress the native tooltips if an element has a `title` attribute. So if you set up your own tooltip implementation, it is better to use some other attribute (say, `data-tip`) instead of `title`.

Comment: you can, if after you attach to the event you clear title attribute

Comment: I see your point, but it’s not about styling native tooltips; it’s about avoiding them (by modifying the DOM).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yep, and i said in my first sentence that it was impossible ;)

Comment: The benefit of using the title attribute and clearing it later is that the tooltip is still available if the user has JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot style the default browser tooltip. But you can use javascript to create your own custom HTML tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a native solution proposed for this using `::tooltip` as the pseudo-element. See [the CSSWG discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/8930) and [decision](https://github.com/mozilla/wg-decisions/issues/1278).

Hopefully implementation progress will be made soon.

Answer (score -5):

```
a[title="My site"] {
    color: red;
}
```

This also works with any attribute you want to add for instance:

HTML

```
<div class="my_class" anything="whatever">My Stuff</div>
```

CSS

```
.my_class[anything="whatever"] {
    color: red;
}
```

See it work at: http://jsfiddle.net/vpYWE/1/

Comment: That styles an element with the specified title; not the tooltip title that the browser displays

Comment: Also, `anything` isn’t a valid HTML attribute. For custom attributes use `data-` attributes.