# MVC3 title property on @Html.TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, formatting, mouseover, title

I have a C#.Net MVC3 web app.  I am adding properties to textboxes (and drop down lists) using the HTML helper functions.

```
 @Html.TextBox("Date", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.Date),
  new { @class = "datepicker", @title="Date mouse over text" })
```

Is there a way to format the `@title` text?

**CLARIFICATION**: Italics, bolding, coloring....that type of formatting.

Comment: what kind of format are you looking to do?

Comment: @Bassam....sorry for the delay.  Italics, bolding, coloring....that type of thing

Answer (score 1):

this has a general tip on creating a styled tooltip

[How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

you'll probably need to create your own htmlhelper that creates the textbox with the tooltip span described in the referenced question

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBox("Date", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.Date),
  new { @class = "datepicker", 
      title = string.Format("{0}, {1}", "Hello", "World") })
```

The only reason you use the @ symbol before class is because class is a C# keyword. You would also have to use it for attributes named default, namespace, double, etc.

Title is not a C# keyword. Therefore you do not need to prefix it with the @ symbol.

Comment: He doesn't need it but with or without it the code is equivalent. So I don't see how this solves the problem (which by the way is not very clear from the OP).

Comment: Because he's using `string.Format()` on the title...  though the OP still hasn't clarified what he means by "format".

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this one:

[jquery.tipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin)

You only have to add jquery and tipTip to your page. Then add a short script:

```
$(function(){
    $(".someClass").tipTip();
});
```

Then your textbox should be:

```
@Html.TextBox("Date", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.Date),
  new { @class = "datepicker someClass", @title="Date mouse over text" })
```