# Can CSS uppercase the text shown for the title atribute?

Tags: css, uppercase

Let’s say we have:

```
<a id="link" href="#"  title="i am the title">link</a>
```

Is there a way to use CSS to uppercase the  *"i am the title"* text that will be shown on mouse hover by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

You can select an element by its attribute(s), but not select an *attribute* itself.

A little bit of JavaScript can do it, however...

```
var elem = document.getElementById('link');

elem.title = elem.title.toUpperCase();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r9GM/).

Answer (score 1):

No - title like tooltips are browser dependant, CSS can't change them.

But here's a link that shows how you can make a fake tooltip look like you want with CSS only:
[How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution, provided you are using jQuery.

Here's a live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/WzYkQ/

Comment: `$('.link').attr('title', function(i, title) { return title.toUpperCase(); });`.