# Need tool tip in Capitalize But getting Issue

Tags: c#, html, css

I need tool-tip in capitalize like "Mr Raj Patel". I am using title for tool-tip but its comes as I Save in database.

Html Code :

```
<td class='td_3'><div class='oneline' style='width:"100px !important;text-transform: capitalize;' title='" + item.ClassTeacher + "'> item.ClassTeacher.ToLower() </div></td>
```

item.ClassTeacher is taken Value like I show above "Mr Raj Patel" but in Tool-tip it not comes in capitalize.

also given Screen-shot of tool-tip

[image: Toot-tip image]Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS  `text-transform: capitalize;` will not affect the title attribute (see [Can CSS uppercase the text shown for the title atribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788109/can-css-uppercase-the-text-shown-for-the-title-atribute))

Solution suggested by Alex using Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('divId');
elem.title = elem.title.toUpperCase();
```

Or captilize `item.ClassTeacher` using C# in the Controller or Razor View:

```
string capitalized = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(item.ClassTeacher);
```