# styling an image title attribute using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to style the text we see when we hover over the image. I tried the following but it won’t work:

```html
<body>
    <img src="img.jpg" title = "<span class='title'> title </span>
</body>
```

My style is in `head`. I wonder why it’s being shown as plain text and why style isn’t working.

Comment: No attributes can be styled, only the elements themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Comment: Not a dupe imo since both questions deal with different problems. Doesn't matter if the technical solutions happen to be the same.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nothing is impossible. edited [the solution by Andres Ilich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2011199/2193439) to the question: [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

```css
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[data]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5px ;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<a data="This is the CSS tooltip showing up when you mouse over the link"href="#" class="tip">Link</a>
```

Comment: Didnt know that. Thanks for this soulution! But, better dont use aplpha background for this, [take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/vPz9Q/).

Comment: @Peeyush Kushwaha what about IE8, how to use this on IE8 browsers?

Comment: I'm not sure if IE8 supports this, but if doesn't, you'll have to go with a JS polyfill

Answer (score 6):

Title attributes in IMG tags cannot contain HTML, so you cannot do this.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha You probably saw some sort of tooltips applied

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha - You've probably seen a jQuery plugin at work.

Comment: It is a javascript tooltip that overrides the hover functionality and exposes a hidden element that can be styled.

Comment: OK, go steal their code. You'll probably find they used JavaScript to hack it.

Comment: can anyone give any useful links on how this can be done without need of jquerry or external plugins?

Comment: You're asking for the impossible.

Comment: Yeah, I guess with $100M you could bribe all browser makers to make them work the way YOU want. I guess that would make this possible. In the real here-and-now world, it's not.

Comment: i have found the answer. and answered it on this question myself. check it if you don't believe it

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible directly in html, it will be in the future with the html5 `figure` and `figcaption` element, or it's possible using jquery !
See [HtmlDoctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) for more informations on these elements !

Answer (score 1):

Another great fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/129/
(I can't take credit, but in the same search I found both posts). It's a similar solution but the styling is a bit fancier.

```
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

And HTML:

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. <a href="#" data-title="Hello, i am a link">Vestibulum</a> tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. <a href="#" data-title="This is another link">Mauris placerat</a> eleifend leo.</p>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by this way-

```css
a.tip {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    text-decoration: none
}
a.tip:hover {
    cursor: help;
    position: relative
}
a.tip span {
    display: none
}
a.tip:hover span {
    border: #c0c0c0 1px dotted;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tip">
   <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
   <span>This is the CSS tooltip showing up when you mouse over the link</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-title-attribute) (emphasis mine):

> The title attribute represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. On a link, this could be the title or a description of the target resource; on an image, it could be the image credit or a description of the image; on a paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text; on a citation, it could be further information about the source; on interactive content, it could be a label for, or instructions for, use of the element; and so forth. **The value is text.**

Ergo, only *text* is allowed in the `title` attribute. For a custom HTML tooltip, you must use a custom solution, such as hiding the content by default and showing it on `:hover` with CSS, or using JavaScript to pull from a `data-...` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is display a text when the mouse hovers an image, you can do something using CSS `:hover` state.

Such a solution is described in [this blog post](https://kyleschaeffer.com/pure-css-image-hover).