# Display title on image hover using attr()

Tags: html, css

Can I add [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/) to a image? I tried but its not working.

```css
img[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<img title="Online" alt="Online" height="16px" style="margin-top:-5px;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weboo-2/512/tick.png">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672946/styling-an-image-title-attribute-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pseudo elements [**do not work**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements) with `img`, I suggest you to wrap it inside a `div` and then use the properties. Use can use the `data-*` attributes to replace the title attribute of image.

```css
.image-container:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container" data-title="Online">
  <img alt="Online" height="16px" style="margin-top:-5px;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/weboo-2/512/tick.png">
</div>
```

Comment: If you know it's a duplicate just vote to close (which you did) there is no point in answering...you're just duplicating content.

Comment: But I did not see any answer of using a container in those. If you get it, please link it here. I will delete it.

Comment: Then you should add our answer there..not here....at least I think so. Perhaps pointing to a different "duplicate" :)

Comment: Guess, we will need to reopen this question. Can we?

Comment: Nah...let's leave it...but in general just voting to close is the only thing to do IMO

Comment: do you know guys ? if you can't answer something then please leave it alone.i saw that threads before but they wasn't work.that is why I asked it here.

Comment: Ah. Apologies for the trouble! I have asked to reopen this for you.

Comment: ah.thanks.. :) :) anyway I can use your method :)