# linkable image with a mouseover text

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, popup

I wanted to make this linkable image to have a text in a pop up box (not the type of pop up that is on w3schools, I want a classic yellowish box) when I mouseover. I tried to do it like this

```
<div class="folder1"> 
<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self" >
<img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57"
title="This is some text I want to display." </a>  
</div>
```

Opening the page in the link works great but there is no pop up box when I hover on it. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by "a classic yellowish box" ? a tooltip? please clarify

Comment: something like this http://sites.cognitivescience.co/knowledgebase/_/rsrc/1468750138530/resources/using-google-sites/creating-mouseover-text-with-html/mouseover.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply with CSS, or you can use one of many simple 'tooltip' JavaScript options. Bootstrap for example has this [tooltip functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) built-in, ready to use. If you want something basic, here's a simple CSS-only approach that you can customise to your needs:

```
<!-- padding added here so you can see the pop-up above the folder, not necessary in-page -->    
<div class="folder1" style="padding: 200px;">
  <a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self" class="popper">
    <img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57" />
    <span class="pop-up">This is some text I want to display.</span>
  </a>  
</div>

<style>
  a.popper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .pop-up {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
  }

  a.popper:hover .pop-up,
  a.popper:focus .pop-up {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Basically, you position the `a` tag relatively so that it can have absolutely positioned children, then relying on `a:hover` you show / hide the child using the child element's `display` property.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are setting the `title` attribute to get a tooltip type hint when the element is hovered over. If this is what you are looking to do but perhaps just style the textbox to be, say, yellow, I would suggest using the following:

```css
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[data]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5px ;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*Change this to yellow, or whatever background color you desire*/
}
```

```html
<a data="This is the CSS tooltip showing up when you mouse over the link"href="#" class="tip">Link</a>
```

The above code was provided by [Peeyush Kushwaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412255/peeyush-kushwaha) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673941/9986900). Simply change the anchor tag to your image tag, and apply styles as you see fit.

---

If by 'popup' you are looking for an alert to the user that requires interaction to close, you can use `window.alert('text')` in javascript in conjunction with the `onmouseover` event handler.

```html
<img src="some_image.png" height="46px" width="57px" onmouseover="window.alert('Some Message')"/>
```

---

Otherwise, if you are looking for another element to be displayed upon mouseover of the image, you can use a bit of javascript to display a div or paragraph (really anything) upon mouseover of the img.

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('popupBox').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#popupBox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="some_image.png" width="41px" height="57px" onmouseover="showDiv()"/>
<div id="popupBox">Some Popup Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can equally try this using css pseudo-element

```css
a{
  position: relative;
}



a:hover:after{
  display:block;
  content: "This is some text I want to display";
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="folder1" style="margin: 70px">
<a href="yourlinkhere" target="_self" class="">
<img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png" height="46" width="57"
</a>
</div>
```