# Changing font on HTML img title

Tags: html, css, angular

I have developed code so you can hover over an image and see text to the side of it. I need to change the font size  from the default. Online other people said it can't be done but wanted others opinions.
Here is my code

HTML

```
<img class="image" src="../../assets/images/image.PNG" alt="" title="
                                The quick, brown fox jumps 
                                over a lazy dog. DJs flock 
                                by when MTV ax quiz prog.
                                Junk MTV quiz graced by
                                "></h3>
```

CSS

```
.image {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  transform: scale(.8);
  **font-family: Univers-Next-Pro-Regular; - the font I want**
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [styling an image title attribute using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672946/styling-an-image-title-attribute-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed font style in your device, you can use it as default by

```
 * {
 font-family: Univers-Next-Pro-Regular;
}
```

Otherwise, you have to download through [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) or other websites, install it, put it in your project folder and call it through `css`.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use font-size or download font-family in google.