# CSS / HTML only popup solution for hover over link, to contain text, links and images

Tags: html, css, popup

What I want is perhaps too simple, and I'm a bit overwhelmed by the responses I find!

****I'd prefer a pure CSS/HTML solution as I don't use javascript.****

What I'm doing at the moment is to use the TITLE attribute within an anchor tag to display information about the link (see: http://www.helpdesk.net.au/index_safety_driver.html and mouseover some of the links).

What I'd like to do is to have something a bit more flexible and interesting for that content and so I'm looking at floating a DIV over a link on hover instead of TITLE (can I leave TITLE in in case the DIV isn't supported - as a failsafe?).

I like the concept at http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ but would like to have the option of an image in the top left corner.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my updated jsfiddle. Using general css classes which you can reuse and with fade effect and with mouse out delay.
The first two css classes are what you need in your code, rest is just for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ctJ3d/8/

```
.popupBox {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;        
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s,opacity 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition-delay:  1s;

}
.popupHoverElement:hover > .popupBox {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition-delay:  0s;        
}       

#button {
    background:#FFF;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:27px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #dadada;
    margin:15px 0 0 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#two {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    color: #333333;
    overflow:hidden;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}

<div id="button" class="popupHoverElement">
    <h3>hover</h3>

    <div id="two" class="popupBox">Hovered content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve whatever I understood from your question. Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_vadnal/RKxZj/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="button"><h3>button</h3>
<div id="two">Hovered content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
background:#FFF;
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:30px;
line-height:27px;
display:block;
border:1px solid #dadada;
margin:15px 0 0 10px;
text-align:center;
}
#two {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
border: 1px solid #DADADA;
color: #333333;
width:98px;
height: 0;
overflow:hidden;
left: 0;
line-height: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
#button:hover > #two {
display:block;
left:0px;
height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Implemented this at http://www.helpdesk.net.au/index_safety_cloud.html and it works fine.  All I have to do is to work on the styling.  Thank you so much for a clean solution.

Comment: When I can get my brain in gear, I'll check out the tutorials.

Comment: I'm not too worried about supporting browsers more than two versions old, but do like to keep IE, Firefox, Chrome happy.  Thank you again.

Comment: Agrh, got to stop hitting the Enter key for a new line!

Can tghe CSS be used without DIV's? or by setting divs to stay inline with text?  What I was originally after (but didn't specify LOL) is that I'd like to have a hover over words in a paragraph, and for supplimentary text to appear on hover..  Can you help out there?

Comment: Thank you all.  it helped a lot.  I also found some more help at  http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

/*  Start of tooltips code */
  .tooltip {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000; outline: none;
   cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
   position: relative;
  }
  .tooltip span {
   margin-left: -999em;
   position: absolute;
  }

Comment: .tooltip:hover span {
   border-radius: 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

Comment: -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
   position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99;
   margin-left: 0; width: 250px;
  }
  .tooltip:hover img {
   border: 0; margin: -10px 0 0 -55px;
   float: left; position: absolute;
  }
  .tooltip:hover em {
   font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;
   display: block; padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
  }

Comment: .classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
  .custom { padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em; }
  * html a:hover { background: transparent; }
  .classic {background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; }
  .critical { background: #FFCCAA; border: 1px solid #FF3334; }
  .help { background: #9FDAEE; border: 1px solid #2BB0D7; }
  .info { background: #9FDAEE; border: 1px solid #2BB0D7; }
  .warning { background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; } /*  End of tooltips code */

Comment: Problem is, whilst it's a great step, and starting to look good, there's overlap and out-of-DIV issues to fix - working on that!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial called [Sexy Tooltips with Just CSS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/) that might be exactly what you're looking for. There are two things to watch for:

1. This solution requires that your tooltip be in your HTML markup, instead of reading from the `title` attribute directly. In a semantic approach to HTML, this strikes me as the wrong approach. Using CSS3, it's possible to utilize the `title` attribute as the value of the `content` property for a psuedo-element. However, without using Javascript to cancel the default tooltip, both tooltips will appear (see this [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/jd77U/)). A much lengthier discussion of this technique, its implementation and issues, can be found at [CSS3 Only Tooltips](http://www.paulund.co.uk/css3-only-tooltips) and [Stack Overflow: How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)
2. If you are still providing support for older browsers, be aware the IE7 will not obey the `:hover` selector for anything but `A` tags. If you need the tooltips to appear in IE7 for any element but an `A` tag, you'll need to use Javascript to add/remove a class from the element on hover and style using that class.

Comment: Thanks for the leads to the tutorials, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="one"><h3>hover over me</h3>
    <div id="two">Hovered content</div>
</div>

#one {
    background:#443322;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#two {
    background:#223344;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#one:hover #two {
    display:block;
    left:100px;
}
```