# Is it possible to style certain text inside of a title attribute?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a link `<a href="#" title="Hello, World!">`. I want to style *parts* of the `title` tooltip attribute. For example, I want to have the `Hello` part be bold. I'm **not** trying to style both `Hello` and `World`, just the `Hello` part.

I have tried putting HTML tags inside of the attribute, but they appear to have no effect (if I enter `<a href="#" title="<b>Hello,</b> World!">`, the title text prints out `<b>Hello,</b> World!`, which is not what I want. I have made a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CWPrZ/) of what happens.

Is it possible to do this using **pure CSS?**

Also, I have seen [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2011142) but it's not what I wanted. It's close, however.

Comment: No. The title tooltip can't be modified or styled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put HTML in the attribute title, it's not a valid code but I beleive you can use **hint.css** library: http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/. Completely css-based and easy-to-use:

```
<a href="http://somewhere/" class="hint  hint--bottom" data-hint="Hello" title="Hello world">Your link</a>
```

Comment: Hmm, looks interesting. Thanks! I'm going to try that.

Comment: @boj You're welcome. For styling, you could create a css class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way for you to achieve what you want is to make a div with the style you want, hide it, and on hover - show it.

Comment: Or use [this](http://www.opentip.org/). However, I was wondering if it was possible in CSS.