# Style tooltip for elements with [title] attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I style a tooltip for elements with [tittle] in order to work on IE8.

here are few fiddle example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Dqr76/9/

```
a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/

```
a[data]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5px ;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

how can I make them work on IE8?

Thank you!

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag

Comment: People are going to need more information if they are going to help you. Do you already have an example working in a different browser? Or are you asking someone to implement this functionality for you? If the answer is the latter you will need to provide more details.

Comment: @Kyle I want that example to work on IE8, what more details ....?

Comment: @RulerNature Give some more details such as; it's working in X browser (e.g. Chrome, Firefox etc) and a screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: @Kiz I don't know what more details you want guys, I want that styled tooltip from my fiddle examples to work on IE8 .