# Applying style to a hyperlink title

Tags: html, css

I need some help. How can I manage a title of a hyperlink for example if I got a hyperlink like this

```
<a href="#" title="Hello">Press here</a>
```

How can I change the font and the size of the word 'Hello'?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2011142/1420197

Comment: I think you need to be more precise in terms of your question, if you are looking for how to edit the title attribute, which is the hover text for the link, in terms of CSS, use @Johnツ answer, otherwise you will need to determine if you want to style everything that has a title of 'Hello' or can be done by classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `a[data-title]:hover` to style it (instead of `title`).

Example:

### HTML

```
<a href="#" data-title="Nice CSS title">Test</a>
```

### CSS

```
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UrvjP/)

Comment: This is not what OP asks. You can style ':after' but then you will have two titles, which looks worse as it was before.

Comment: +1 Although this isn't really styling the browsers' title popup, but rather creating a new one. The issue with this is that you now have two title popups...

Comment: @dfsq I guess that it's the browser default. But this is the closest solution...

Comment: You can get even closer if you use 'data-title="Hello"' instead of title. `content: attr(data-title);` This way title will not show up.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. Just change `title` attribute with `tip`,  and browser's title popup won't display. see:http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/1/

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't it's a browser default .. however what you can do is use a small jQuery plugin for tooltips & you will have total control over the look of the elements appearing on hover.
[Check this link for example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/01/how-to-create-animated-tooltips-with-css3/)

Comment: With CSS3 it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17466299/1420197

Comment: @Johnツ No it's not possible. Styling pseudo element `:after` and changing default title style are not the same.

Comment: exactly @dfsq , there is no control over the title attribute ... and the best option is using a span that acts as a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, you can't change the styling of Title attribute inside a tag. I mean you can but there's some browser incompatibilities. 
I think the best solution is that you make a specific class for that a tag and inside that a tag put span. 
Something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="pop">Press here <span>Hello</span></a>

a.pop {
color: blue;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative
}

a.pop:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

a.pop span {
display:none;
}

a.pop:hover span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left:0;
z-index:100;
background: grey;
padding: 5px 10px;
font-size:13px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
}
```