# Change title font size and background

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, title

I have one title like

`<a title="I am your title"/>`

default color of background is yellow

[image]

This is the image which give you more idea what i am talking about

and font color black is there any way to change color of background and increase font-size  of title by using CSS?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag

This should now be possible due to CSS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style this kind of 'title' (tooltip) without a headache.

Instead, I would suggest you opt for an alternative tooltip if heavy customisation and styling are a requirement.

For example:

http://tooltipsy.com/

The above is a really lite, basic jquery plugin, but will allow you to style it as you please.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own markup to display the tooltip as the native tooltips can't be modified.

Check out this thread for more help. [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Comment: this should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need some kind of custom programming, jQuery or something else. This kind ot tooltip is formatted only by the OS and the browser.