# SVG 'Title' tooltip styling with multiple titles

Tags: javascript, css, svg, styles, tooltip

I have an SVG map of the United States that has a tooltip for each county, displaying the county name and state (see picture for clarification)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DA6R.png

Here's a sample of the svg code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg height="351.667" id="svg9559" version="1.0" width="555.221" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <metadata id="metadata3671">
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>
     image/svg+xml
    </dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <defs id="defs9561"/>
 <g id="stylegroup" style="fill:#d0d0d0;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1">
  <path d="M 62.678,259.312 L 63.560,258.431 L 64.220,257.991 L 64.439,258.431 L 64.000,258.651 L 64.439,258.651 L 66.643,257.991 L 68.626,255.566 L 70.388,256.448 L 70.388,256.890 L 69.727,257.549 L 69.727,258.212 L 70.388,257.991 L 70.829,256.890 L 71.269,256.448 L 71.930,257.108 L 72.150,257.991 L 72.811,258.212 L 73.030,257.771 L 74.131,257.549 L 75.894,257.549 L 76.113,257.771 L 75.673,258.431 L 75.673,258.651 L 76.996,258.872 L 76.774,259.532 L 77.656,259.532 L 78.757,258.872 L 81.180,258.651 L 82.722,259.092 L 83.386,259.092 L 84.044,259.312 L 84.267,259.532 L 85.148,259.532 L 86.249,259.312 L 87.572,259.312 L 89.114,259.754 L 89.554,259.532 L 90.436,258.872 L 90.655,258.651 L 91.096,258.212 L 92.639,258.431 L 96.163,259.532 L 97.264,263.058 L 97.925,265.261 L 88.893,267.464 L 89.334,269.886 L 87.572,270.327 L 82.945,271.211 L 82.722,271.211 L 72.371,272.311 L 69.947,272.311 L 69.947,271.870 L 68.186,271.870 L 68.186,271.429 L 66.423,271.429 L 64.661,271.649 L 63.338,271.649 L 63.338,271.211 L 62.678,271.211 L 62.678,271.429 L 60.696,271.429 L 60.255,271.211 L 60.034,271.211 L 60.034,271.429 L 59.154,271.429 L 58.932,270.989 L 57.831,270.989 L 57.831,271.429 L 57.389,271.429 L 54.304,271.211 L 54.304,272.089 L 52.762,272.089 L 51.441,271.429 L 50.780,270.547 L 51.220,269.227 L 51.441,267.683 L 52.983,267.905 L 54.967,267.683 L 55.626,267.464 L 56.948,265.921 L 57.611,263.939 L 58.932,261.957 L 59.814,261.074 L 60.474,261.297 L 61.356,260.855 L 62.678,259.312" id="02185">
   <title id="t0">
    North Slope, AK
   </title>
  </path>
  <path d="M 74.350,278.699 L 73.911,278.699 L 73.030,279.139 L 73.251,279.580 L 71.930,279.580 L 71.930,280.901 L 71.048,281.122 L 71.048,280.682 L 70.608,280.243 L 69.727,280.243 L 69.727,281.122 L 68.845,281.122 L 68.845,280.243 L 67.084,280.243 L 67.084,282.225 L 64.881,282.225 L 64.881,283.105 L 63.560,283.105 L 63.560,285.308 L 63.119,285.308 L 63.119,285.750 L 62.678,285.750 L 54.967,285.529 L 54.967,284.647 L 54.745,284.647 L 54.526,284.427 L 54.526,283.767 L 54.085,283.546 L 54.085,281.784 L 53.863,279.580 L 54.745,279.580 L 55.186,279.800 L 54.745,281.342 L 54.967,282.225 L 58.932,282.663 L 60.034,281.563 L 60.696,281.563 L 60.474,281.122 L 59.814,280.682 L 59.154,280.243 L 58.269,279.139 L 57.831,278.920 L 57.611,278.259 L 57.831,278.038 L 58.269,278.038 L 58.932,279.580 L 59.814,280.461 L 60.255,280.243 L 59.814,280.022 L 59.154,279.139 L 59.594,277.818 L 59.814,278.038 L 59.814,277.818 L 59.154,277.378 L 58.052,277.597 L 57.169,277.597 L 55.626,276.937 L 54.967,274.514 L 52.762,272.089 L 54.304,272.089 L 54.304,271.211 L 57.389,271.429 L 57.831,271.429 L 57.831,270.989 L 58.932,270.989 L 59.154,271.429 L 60.034,271.429 L 60.034,271.211 L 60.255,271.211 L 60.696,271.429 L 62.678,271.429 L 62.678,271.211 L 63.338,271.211 L 63.338,271.649 L 64.661,271.649 L 66.423,271.429 L 68.186,271.429 L 68.186,271.870 L 69.947,271.870 L 69.947,272.311 L 71.710,272.311 L 71.710,273.412 L 72.150,273.412 L 72.150,273.853 L 73.030,274.735 L 73.030,276.055 L 73.911,276.055 L 74.350,276.496 L 74.572,277.818 L 74.350,278.699" id="02188">
   <title id="t1">
    Northwest Arctic, AK
   </title>
  </path>
```

Notice that in each "path" element there is a "title" element. The title element automatically displays the tooltip.

How do I create a style for all of the title tooltips? I'm basically looking for a style to apply across the board to every tooltip

Comment: <title> element tooltips cannot be styled. If you need styling, roll your own from scratch.

Comment: Do you have any resources that show how to do this?

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703318/is-it-possible-to-enhance-the-default-appearance-of-svg-title-tooltip