# How to format utf8_encode messages?

Tags: php, formatting

I'm using the function utf8_encode to properly display some latin accents (ã,á,à..) in a tooltip message.

However I'd like to bold some words and html tags don't work.

Is it possible to format these messages?

**UPDATE**:

I don't want to format the whole text using css, I want to turn just a single word into **bold**.
I have this constructor in PHP where I can pass some parameters to construct the textbox. A simplified version:

```
TextBox($id,$title){
          echo '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'"  title="'.$title.'">';    
}
```

The title parameters I'm using is something like:

```
$title = utf8_encode("Example ã, blabla à");
```

And I'd like to bold just the first word, for example.

Comment: show some code that will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Comment: @Boann, I wanna format a single word, not the whole thing (thing I've already done, btw).

Comment: @carla Not possible with the title attribute. Also, utf8_encode has nothing whatsoever to do with this.

Comment: @Boann, Yeah, it seems you're right about the utf8 thing. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Maybe you can find your answer in this article:
http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

It talks about css selectors for selecting stuff like first-word, last-word etc. It also mentions https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js

Comment: I don't want to format the whole text, just a single word.

Comment: Changed answer to previous feedback

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info, I didn't know it was possible to use CSS like this. I don't know if I can pick the first word of a title attribute using that but I'll  take a look.