# How to change the color of background of title tag?

Tags: html, css, hover

**See this image...** 
[image]

There is a title tag that hovers over each one of the social icons. I am trying to change the background color of the bubble where the title tag is.

I have tried this...

```
a[title]:hover:after { background: #8b6ab2; }
```

But it's not working. Is there a general way this can be done, or does it have to be dynamic based on the website?

Comment: It isn't working because the background is behind the picture. Do you want to change the

Comment: can you link us to that page?

Comment: The site is at **[AZEverything](http://azeverything.com/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way.

```
<a href="#" title="This is the title to show">hover here</a>
<style type="text/css">
  a[title]:hover:after{
    content: attr(title);
    background: red; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 10%;}
 </style>
```

You can hide default title by using a data attribute like this

```
<a href="#" data-title="This is the title to show">hover here</a>
<style type="text/css">
a[data-title]:hover:after{
  content: attr(data-title);
  background: red; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
}
</style>
```

see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Comment: I know yours is correct, but it's not working. The site is at **[Click Here](http://azeverything.com/)**. You'll see the social icons I'm referring to at the bottom, far left footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding !important to the end of the CSS rule. It's likely whatever CSS framework you are using for the tooltip is overriding your CSS.