# Is there an HTML5 validation API to set the state of an element to be invalid?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to use the HTML 5 validation API but for one thing. I will do my custom validation using JavaScript but I would like to use the nice tool-tip like thingy that the browser uses to display the validation message.

So, in short, I'd like to selectively use the `element.setCustomValidity("my own message")` in my own event handler, so I can avoid using a third-party tool-tip.

However, even though I set the custom validity, it won't display until I *somehow invalidate the state of the controls*.

If I call into the validation API (`element.checkValidity()`), it will start doing its own in-built validation looking for attributes on my HTML elements. But I don't want any of that.

```
function submitEventHandler() {
  let errors = myOwnValidateFunction();

  if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
     let txt = document.getElementById("txt");
     txt.setCustomValidity("No, no, no, no, you're doing it wrong!");

    // Is there a way to invalidate an HTML element?
    // ...???

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use your `submitEventHandler` to handle `onsubmit` event from form? Can you try to return `false` from it?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Yes, and I am already doing that (and/or `event.preventDefault()`). But that's only to stop the form from posting. That doesn't relate to the validation API. :-)

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the error tooltip is the same as the title attribute, why don't you set up the title attribute to contain the message on the input wit the error? (if you just want that tooltip)

Comment: @Art3mix That's *exactly* another thing I wanted to avoid. That too is a bunch of work compared to the validation API. If only I knew a way to mark controls of my choice as invalid in one function call, that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as always, each browser simply act differently on pretty much any new API.

To invalidate an input, its enough to set this: `input.setCustomValidity('just an error');`, this will let the browser know this input have an issue with it.

**HOWEVER** each browser will do its own things:

**Chrome** - Won't show any error until you try to submit the form, only than it will let the user know that the ***first*** field with an error have an error, it will ignore the rest of the inputs with errors.

**Firefox** - will show your custom message and highlight the input in red right away after you set it, you don't need to wait for a submit to show the errors, when submit is clicked it shows a different tooltip on the invalid input.

**Edge** - Will show an tooltip with custom message only after the user hover over it, and will highlight in red with different tooltip after submit

Didn't test it on other browsers, but i'm sure each browser will use its own way of showing the error, some might wait for submit, some will show right away, but all who support this API should invalid the input after you `input.setCustomValidity('Some error message')`

This is why you might consider showing your own tooltip to avoid this browser dependency, and make sure its working the same way on all of them.

https://jsfiddle.net/q60bwteL/17/

**Update**

You don't need to set any type, and the validation above works the same way for `type='text'`, i'm not sure what you see, but the code snippet below have 2 inputs, 1 with no type and 1 with `type='text'`, both works.

You can create a fiddle with your issue so I could take a look, but as you can see from the fiddle, its working for all type of inputs:
https://jsfiddle.net/q60bwteL/21/

But again, note that it works differently on different browsers, chrome only shows the first field with the error, not all of them and only on submit, while firefox shows errors for all of the fields (if have multiple errors) and before you click on submit.

This is why I personally never trust the implementation of the browser with stuff I could do on my own, it is very easy to implement a basic error handling stuff, from the question you already have it, you simply need to add the styling and the tooltip to it, there are many ways to create a tooltip with CSS alone on the web (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391104/8727608).

Create a function that will handle your error things:

```
function setError(inputElement, errorMessage) {
  inputElement.setAttribute('title', 'errorMessage');
  inputElement.classList.add('errorInput') 
}
```

Create a function that will remove all the error things:

```
function removeError(inputElement) {
  inputElement.removeAttribute('title');
  inputElement.classList.remove('errorInput') 
}
```

And style the errorInput class as you wish with CSS.

Now I assume you only return the errors in array of strings with the error messages, but you can use an array of objects that each object contain the error message and the input element which have the error:

```
if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
  for(var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {        
    setError(errors[i].element, errors[i].message);
  }
}
```

Before you validate the input simply call the removeError function and don't forget to return false when you submit if there are errors. (as you already do)

**UPDATE 2**

I don't know why I didn't think of it. but there is a way to stop validation and start it when you want:

Adding the [novalidate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) attribute on the form will let the browser know that you don't want to perform a validation on that form, so this won't show any errors and will handle submit as you like it to.

But you still want to use that validation and for this you can call the [reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) on the form element, basically this function enable the validation on submit, it doesn't matter where you call it, it will run the validation when submit is clicked **BUT** this will show only the first input with the error message and not all of them (even on firefox), it looks like there are 2 states of validation, the before and after submit, not sure why, but those are 2 different checks, and you can only control the after submit check, not the before.

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q60bwteL/64/

So you can control when you do the validation, but there are 2 types of validation, before and after submit, you can control only after submit, and it only show the first input error not all of them.
Do we like it? no, why its like that? I have no idea, to be honest, it really looks like the firefox developers simply break the loop after first error is found.

P.S - after thinking about it, they simply implement the title attribute tooltip method, but because only 1 element can be hovered or focused they can only show 1 error message, this is how tooltips works.

Comment: Thing is: you're setting the HTML5 validation attributes (`type = email|url`) in your example. As stated in my question, I *don't* want to use any HTML 5 validation; I want to *do my own validation in JavaScript*. I only want to use *the visual part* of the validation API, i.e. the thingies that appear when controls contain invalid input, so I don't have to invest all the effort in creating tool-tips or using third-party controls. Thank you for the quite a bit of effort you invested in this answer.

Comment: Thanks again for such an investment. I appreciate it. My question, though, stands as it were. There are many problems with the validation API out of the box, For .e.g., as you note one about only the first field showing the tool-tip thingy. One more is that the validation API also invalidates the controls every page load. *Involuntary validation*, i.e. you and me as developer having no control over *when* the validation will happen, is the butt of the issue -- if only it exposed a way to trigger and suppress control validation, all would fall into place.

Comment: PS: I know how to create a tool-tip and use third-parties as well. The question was to avoid having to do either of those. :-)

Comment: I know you do, I just gave a fast way for other developers who will look into this. You are right, this is the problem with so many browsers, you can't rely on any implementation, so in the end the best way would be to do it on your own, browsers seems to forget that developers must develop for all of the browsers, and implement so many stuff differently without a reason, yea sure your browser is cool and can do THAT, but it won't help me if i can't use it on different browsers ..., BTW found a way to semi-control the validation, see update 2 @WaterCoolerv2