# email verification and number length not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two text fields where id like to have a form check if the number and email is valid before registration. the email needs to be in the correct format and the number needs to have exactly 11 digits. failing to match either will show an error message.

in the email I tried a validate email functions with the format and symbols required are in the variable. as for the number i tried "c.length !== 11"

whenever i try to click the register button, nothing changes.

[image: form]

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function validateEmail(v_email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(v_email);
}

document.getElementById("register").onclick = function () {

var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;


  let c = contact.val() + ''; // make sure it's a string
  c = c.trim()// trim it
  if (c.length !== 11) {
      document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "Contact Number";
  }


  if (validateEmail(v_email)) {
    document.getElementById("email_label").innerHTML = "Email";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("email_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid email address</span>";
  }


return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post">
  <div class="container rg_box">
    <br>

    <label id="number_label"><b>Contact Number</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" autocomplete="off"
    value="<?php
      if(isset($_POST["contact"])) {
        echo($_POST["contact"]);
      } ?>">

    <label id="email_label"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"
    value="<?php
      if(isset($_POST["email"])) {
        echo($_POST["email"]);
      } ?>">

      <input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER">
      <br><br>

      <p class="text-align-center">Already have an account? <a href="index.php">Login Here</a><p>
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem? what is going wrong and doesn't work?

Comment: why do you  use in input tag for email type="text" and no type="email"...?

Comment: 1st comment: nothing happens when i click on my register button

Comment: First you don't use the right variable when passing to the email validation function `validateEmail(v_email)` should be `validateEmail(email)`, second you already got the value from the input: `contact.val()` contact holds the value of the input already, it doesn't have .val() function. you should see the error about it in your console.

Comment: 2nd comment: im trying to get my variable to work on the text field.

Comment: And last one, you return false no matter what, so you will never successfully submit this form.

Comment: where would i place the return false?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: @Hadrian Check my answer for  short and quick way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mini errors, but this code below should work as expected (didn't test it)

Changes:

1. `contact` variable doesn't have a `val` function because its a string (or int), the `contact` variable already holds the value of the input.
2. `validateEmail` got the wrong parameter, you copied the function declaration but forgot to change the passed variable to `email`
3. Added `flag` var so you could know if error happened, when there is an error our flag will be true, so later we check - if the flag is true, we had an error so don't continue, just `return false;`

Should work now.

```
function validateEmail(v_email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(v_email);
}

document.getElementById("register").onclick = function () {

var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var flag = false;

  let c = contact + ''; // make sure it's a string
  c = c.trim()// trim it
  if (c.length !== 11) {
      document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid contact number (must contain 11 digits)</span>";
flag = true;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("number_label").innerHTML = "Contact Number";
  }

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    document.getElementById("email_label").innerHTML = "Email";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("email_label").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Invalid email address</span>";
flag = true;
  }

if(flag) {
  return false;
} 
}
```

**NOTE** :
About contact variable, you only check if its length is 11, which means that "Im just tst" will pass your tests.
First rule in forms, you ***MUST NOT*** trust any input  from the user, and must check the input on the server.

Best way is to do a "Shallow" tests in Javascript just to make sure all the obvious things are checked, and then do a serious check of the input in your back-end (your PHP code)

Comment: i see the small mistakes i made, thanks for the information, helped out so much. and i got the contact variable noted too

Comment: console is your best friend, use it, console.log your variable to see what they holds, and you see errors there, if this answer helped you mark it as the answer, if you still have errors with this code, edit the question and include them, (also comment here to let me know about it) @HadrianClayton

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript to validate the email or to limit the `#contact` input to `11`. You can validate an email input by just using the attribute `type="email"` and you can use `maxlength="11"` to limit the `#contact` input length. Finally, add the `required` attribute to make sure the contact form won't submit unless the inputs are validated.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="11" id="contact" name="contact" required>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
```

---

However you do need to use a bit of JavaScript to make sure all input characters in `#contact` is a number.

---

Here's a **Code Snippet** with the necessary JavaScript added and the above attributes defined:

```js
/* JavaScript */

document.getElementById("contact").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode !== 8 && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)){
     e.preventDefault(); // refuse input if the key inputted is not either a number or the BACKSPACE key
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post">
  <div class="container rg_box">
    <br>

    <label id="number_label"><b>Contact Number</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" maxlength="11" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" autocomplete="off" required>
    <hr />
    <label id="email_label"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required>
    <hr />
      <input type="submit" class="btn form-control color-white mwc-orange-background-color" id="register" name="register" value="REGISTER">
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's important to note that this has a lot of limitations and each browser have its own way of validating the data and showing errors, more details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53969802/8727608

Comment: thanks on expanding the number issue and the info on the browser