# How to change the tooltip (title of the div) background color in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the below html, how to apply the styling using span for the title attribute of the div. I applied a background color for the id 'tooltip-value' and it was not applied in this case, how to make it work?

Here is the jsfiddle link,
http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/qtyL1rdm/

```
   <div class="tooltip">
        <div id='column1' title='<span id="tooltip-value">1</span>' style="width: 40px;">1</div> 
        <div id='column2' title="2" style="width: 20px;">2 </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style default tooltip but you can use `data-attributes` for styling this messege with using `content:attr(data-attribute);`

```
.tooltip{padding:20px 0;}
.tooltip div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
#column1 {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

#column1:after{
    content:attr(data-title);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:100%;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}
#column1:hover:after{display:block;}
#column2 {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: Red;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
#column2:after{
    content:attr(data-title);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:100%;
    color:#000;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}
#column2:hover:after{display:block;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfg16va2/)