# put an image bg to a title on image

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I created a sample image that has an image title when hovered. I want to have the title to have a background image, inside that is the text, as shown below:

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="footerimages">
<a href="#" target="_blank"  title="Bread" ><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" height="300px" width="300px"></a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.footerimages img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44zdsvfp/1/)

Comment: take a look to [bootstrap tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-examples)

Comment: im using foundation press as framework.

Comment: create your own tooltip http://www.cssportal.com/css-tooltip-generator/

Comment: I think someone had a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8788410/1449519

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can't include an image inside a `title` attribute</s>, but you can use CSS to get the same effect.

**EDIT** I stand corrected; you can style the title tag with CSS using `#div[title]`. BUT, the browser still shows the default tooltip.

Let's call your hover image #pop. On hover of your first image, #pop will be displayed at your desired location.

```
 #pop{
background:red;
width:30px;
height:30px;
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:29px;
border:2px solid black;
}
.footerimages img:hover + #pop{
display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44zdsvfp/3/)

**Useful Info:** I did a quick search and found a way to emulate the tooltip by using the `data` attribute.

For example, you would have `<a href="#" data-title="Your title here"></a>` and style it calling it like so: `a[data-title]`

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag?lq=1) Look at the first answer's comments to see what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is holding the `pointer down` image, then use this:

```
.footerimages{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Note: Apply the `.footerimages` 's parent container some position value other than "static".