# How to Center a Button Image and make it navigate to next article?

Tags: html, css, button, menu, scroll

Guys let me start over it seems nobody gets my simple question. We are not all Pro's when it comes to coding. So please have patience with me I am still learning. I just want to know which part of my html/css code do you require to get a better understanding of what I want to create.

So to describe what I have now:

1 index.html 
2 style.css

At the top of my website there is a background image which is within a slide container. The menu is a minimal open/close button floating on the right.

Now I want to use an image file of an arrow, align this in the center of my background image and use it to navigate to the next section of my website which is called "About Me". I know how to link for example an index.html to about.html file, but in this case I have a single index file where the menu buttons/sections are in a div and li class a linked as ahref.

So my question is what do I need to do to make that arrow button link to ahref"Aboutme" section. What and where do I have to put in this code in html and css. I have a lot of code available but please tell me which part you need.

Thanks for your help

```
<!-- HOME (SLIDER) -->
<section id="home" class="notoppadding text-light">
    <div class="section-inner">


    <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
    <div class="rev-slider-container">
        <div class="rev-slider" >
            <ul>

                <!-- THE FIRST SLIDE -->
                <li data-transition="slidedown" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="1200" >
                    <!-- THE MAIN IMAGE IN THE FIRST SLIDE -->
                    <img src="files/uploads/slider-bg1.jpg"   alt="slidebg1"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">

                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->    
                    <div class="tp-caption srcaption-bigwhite lft ltb"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="0"
                    data-speed="800"
                    data-start="400"
                    data-easing="easeInOutQuad"
                    data-endspeed="800"
                    data-endeasing="easeInOutQuad"
                    style="z-index: 2"><strong></strong>
                    </div>

                </li> <!-- end first slide -->

                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- END .rev-slider-container -->        
    <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
```

Comment: `which is under href and not .html page` is a bit unclear. Also post the minimal code to reproduce your issue, if you have any.

Comment: Please paste your actual code, not an image of code.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia All fine, but I did not asked for an image (although it helps to *get a picture*) but for some CODE. You know, CSS, HTML. (there's several ways you can input your code for us to test it.)

Comment: @DiegoGarcia please... don't put code in comments. Click [edit] and use the proper code tools you have available. Also we need some CSS.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia I don't understand this part `move to the next page down called "About" which is under href in the menu and not a .html page`

Comment: @DiegoGarcia you should read my Comments with more patience and know the difference from the Comment sections (which is where we comment now) and the **Question Edit**. So after you read again carefully my comments you'll notice that I've told you to: **NOT** put code here in comments; but rather **INSIDE YOUR OWN QUESTION** and if you click this link [edit] (which I've already shared with you) you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: Have you taken a look at my answer? It would be nice we move in the comment section over there, to see if it helped to solve your questions.

Comment: So you have only an image to share with us but no code samples? Just for example see how other people ask for help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305678/only-half-of-hover-menu-appears they include all the needed code to (hopefully) resolve the issue. As you can see the guy did not shared any code that is unrelated to the question. Your question as it stands is Off-topic for many reasons and is pending-close. Please read carefully [ask] and [help] to learn how this site works.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan roko thanks for your help so far...but thats why I ask which part of the code do you need. In terms of the button I have nothing. I can upload the whole index.html file but SOF won't allow me obviously.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zevawa/1/)***

```
<a class="nextpageLink" href="#about"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.nextpageLink{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom: 10px;
   width:80px;
   height:80px;
   background: url(img/next.png) 0 0 ; // 80x160px sprite image
}
.nextpageLink:hover{
   background-position: 0 -80px ;
}
```

let's say you create a sprite image and on button hover you simply change the background position.

```
+-------+    >> 80 x (80*2) px background image
|       |
| gray  |
|       |
+-------+    >> on hover move up by -80px
|       |
| white |
|       |
+-------+
```

---

If you don't want to navigate to another page, than your link needs to **anchor-target** an `ID` element on the page:

```
<a class="nextpageLink" href="#about"></a>
```

so you also need the anchor-related ID - assigned to the `about` element like:

```
<div id="about" class="wrapper">
   <!-- ABOUT DIVS AND CONTENT HERE-->
</div>
```

and your page will scroll.

---

If you want to **scroll with an animation** there's already plenty of similar questions here on stackoverflow that **involve the use of JS**. **Use Goog** or the StackOverflow's search input.

Tip: while you do some Goog to filter only results that are relevant to StackOverflow do like i.e:

> how to animate page scroll :stackoverlfow

Comment: this all does not makes sense. You know what forget I  will check google, this all is above my understanding of coding and it just makes it more complicated. In my eyes what I want is very simple. Its just I don't know how to code it. I know how insert the image button but not where exactly in html/css I have to put in the code. I can send you all the files I have but not sure that's the solution. Thanks for your help Roko.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia added a jsBin demo example in my Answer. I'm not trying to be rude by any kind so sorry in advance, but you cannot expect such answers here. You need always to show some code and an effort to resolve your own issue -first. Otherwise it's like *`"I have no clue so do it for me please"`* kind of question, which is not welcome in this community. Well, take a look and happy coding. Let me know if I was close with my example.

Comment: thanks- I wasn't asking for someone to write the code. I just need guidance. But thanks for the demo it is more or less what I am looking to create. Just now I need to learn what every part of the code means.

Comment: Hi Roko

I appreciate your help yesterday. Perhaps i am in the wrong community to ask these questions. 

Here is a link of what I want. If you can explain to me step by step how I could write the code into my existing code I would really appreciate it.

http://birvacreativestudio.com/theme/springspray/index-navigation3.html

Notice the arrow pointing down and has an internal link to the next page "About". This is what I want. I have an png file in the shape of an arrow and I want to use this as an extra way to navigate in the beginning.

Comment: @DiegoGarcia have you noticed the jsBin demo link in the top of my answer? What's wrong with it?