# Title tooltip text color?

Tags: php, colors, tooltip, title

Is there possible somehow set color on text `Film Tagline:`?

```
$out.= '<span title2="Film Tagline: '.$t.' " class="masterTooltip">...</span>';
```

I mean only set color on text **Film Tagline:** not all tooltip, because there is also some funcsion code

> '.$t.'
>   what need to be stay normal!

Tried many combinations, but can't get working!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag

Comment: Probably you should to change the css for class masterTooltip

Comment: It change all tooltip color, so in same line has code '.$t.' so it need be normal so want try change only text color on Film Tagline: