# Title attribute tooltips and iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I would like to know if you can stylise a title attribute while keeping its' native ability to break the borders of an `iframe`.

Comment: make the description brief and post some example code you have done

Comment: sorry first time doing this ^_^;;, I added some output code, I hope this will assist.

Comment: @Streamline Rogue Why Cant you use tooltip plugins?. And title attribute content in the iframe will come out of iframe if it is more.

Comment: I think its my fault.. i had gone through your question 4 times.. still i did not make anything out of it....

Comment: Nah, I think I just overcomplicated the question, I simplified it for all :D

Comment: Can you use some information from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag) post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to style the title attribute, it's comes from the browser/OS.

Some people use tricks like making a pseudo element with the content of the title attribute, but this would have the same limitations as anything else inside the iframe and would not break out.

Comment: A shame, but I kinda expected this to be the answer. Thanks for clarifying it though :)