# How to show entire content of title attribution

Tags: html

All:

I am new to HTML title attr. Right now, I need to give a long string to element's title attribution, like more than 800 characters. But when I do that, the bubble tooltip automatically hide part of the string.

I wonder how can I disable this auto hiding?

Thanks

Comment: Create your own tooltip.

Comment: @TinyGiant That is my original way, but my boss insist that the string need to in that attribution   ToT

Comment: There is no way to select the tooltip, that's a browser construct. Even [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2011142/4639281)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8788410/4639281) creates a custom tooltip.

Comment: @TinyGiant Thanks, I will talk to my boss again.