# style title tooltip does not work inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to style tooltip `title` by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag). However, it does not work for table. In other words, it seems that `a[title]` works but `th[title]` does not.

see the fiddle modified from the original post, where `th[title]` still uses the default style.
http://jsfiddle.net/5frf7svm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in your CSS:

```
td[title]:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
```

Where do you suppose that's shoving the pseudo element?  That's right, off the page.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4p4jk5hh/

All I did was remove the `left` and `top` attributes.

Comment: thanks! is there a straight forward way to place the custom tooltip at mouse pointer?

Comment: @dragon_cat Not that I can think of off the top of my head.  I wouldn't worry about it though, having it in a fixed location relative to the object being hovered is fine from a UX standpoint.

Comment: the issue is that i am showing tooltips only when ellipsis is activated, so the tooltip can show up to the far right of the actual table cell depending on the real text length (un-truncated) of the current cell.

Answer (score 1):

`th[title]` works fine for me. But position of title in the end of page, because `th` have position `static`.

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

just put an `a` element inside your `th`, like so:

`<td><a title="cell 1 tooltip">table cell 1</a></td>`