# Style hover text box of v-bind:title in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I need to display detailed information as hover text in my Vue.js application. According to this blog (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-hover-effect-in-vue-js/), I can display hover text as 'v-bind:title='parameter'. It works, but the styling looks pretty basic. But is there a way to style that text box?
Or am I going down the wrong path and should I be implementing a hover text box some other way?

Here's a sniped of my vue.js frontend code...

```
<td>
  <div :class="myclass" v-bind:title="detail_info">{{ status }}</div>
</td>
```

I tried adding v-bind:style to the div, but that colored my div, not the hover text box:

```
<td>
  <div :class="myclass" v-bind:title="detail_info" v-bind:style="{'background-color': '#000000'}">{{ status }}</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to style the tooltip or hover text box. You can use CSS to style the default tooltip appearance by targeting the title attribute with the `::before` pseudo-element. Here an example of CSS styling for the standard browser tooltip using a `div` tag with a `title` attribute:

```
div[title]:hover::before {
  content: attr(title);
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This will style the tooltip and you can modify this to fit your needs. Although the styling possibilities of the built-in browser tooltip are rather limited. I would suggest you build your own custom tooltip, which actually isn't that complicated.

A custom tooltip can be a div (or other element) that is displayed when you hover over a specific component. Because of that, it's much easier to style the tooltip and you can use built in functions like CSS `:hover` or Javascript `mouseover` event.
In vue it would be `v-on:mouseover="mouseover"`. You just need to create and style a tooltip element/class that gets displayed once you hover over something. The data in the tooltip can be inserted with JS and the CSS position should be `absolute` for you to easily move it with the mouse cursor coordinates of the client.

Comment: This is really nice. Wish there was a way to do transition on it though. I set position: relative on the titled element then I can add top: 40px to the :hover::before

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the title attribute in HTML. But if you want to change the text / background color of title, you need to consider using **Tooltip**.

1. Start with a tooltip package instead of using native html (Recommend). There is one package you can consider: https://github.com/Akryum/floating-vue
2. Using CSS to create tooltip: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is a `CSS` problem, not `Vue.js`

You are trying to style the `title` attribute and this is **not possible**.

Check these answers on how to do it another way:

1. [How to change the style of the title attribute inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag)
2. [HTML title attribute style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228962/html-title-attribute-style/38232206#38232206)