# How can I create a Help popup

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add a small box next to a question on a form I am asking which when clicked will pop up with a box of text for help about the question. How can i add some java script to create a Pop-up box that will appear when clicked rather than using on mouse over

Comment: So you want a popup to show on click?

Comment: How if you wanted it on focus? With that, it will show the popup when clicked and then disappear when you click somewhere else. Are you ok with that?

Comment: Or you can consider using the ``title`` to help you. see [How to change the style of the title attribute inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2011142/9935654)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Design it as you like.

Note that you can add several help popups. Just add `class="help"` and a `title` containing the help text.

```js
var helpBox = document.getElementById("helpBox");
var helpElements = document.getElementsByClassName("help");

for (var i = 0; i < helpElements.length; i++) {
  helpElements[i]._helpText = helpElements[i].title;
  helpElements[i].removeAttribute("title");
  
  helpElements[i].onclick = function(e) {
    helpBox.style.display = "block";
    helpBox.innerHTML = "<span id='close' title='Close'>X</span>" +
        e.target._helpText;
    
    helpBox.children[0].onclick = function() {
      helpBox.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.help {
  cursor: help;
}

#helpBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#helpBox #close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<span class="help" title="Help text">Help</span>
<div id="helpBox"></div>
```