# how to modify tooltip content font size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I feel the font size of the content of **tooltip** is small. 
For example, the code is as below:

```
<span name="explanation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="hello world!"></span>
```

So how to modify the font size of the showed 'hello world!' when mouse hovering the **span** element?

Comment: Look in the page code what element the tooltip is, maybe it has a class where xou can override the defaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 4):

First, start with the following code into the HTML head section:
Second,  embed a tooltip somewhere on your page using respectivly the following code

```css
 <style type="text/css">
a.tooltip {
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: blue;
}

a.tooltip span {
 display: none;
}

a.tooltip:hover span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
        font-size: 40px;
 left: 0px;
 display: block;
 width: 250px;
 color: black;
 background-color: #FFFF40;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
  <a class="tooltip" href="#">this text<span>This help text is shown in the tooltip. It spans multiple lines and works in all browsers.</span></a>
```

Comment: I has tried it. It indeed is a smart method. Thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery Tooltip` is a good choice. the font size is larger and favorite for me.