# Styling the Title Inside Input Tag

Tags: html, css

is there any way to Style the Title inside The Tag?
i mean for an example :

```
<input type= "submit" id="submit" title= "submit your form">
```

i want to know is it possible to style this title inside the  input tag?

Comment: You can with CSS3. Have a look here [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But you may try some trick with it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var old_title;
  $('.title-styled').on('mouseover', function(){
    old_title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('.title-message').html($(this).attr('title')).css('visibility', 'visible');
    
    $(this).attr('title', '');
  });
  
  $('.title-styled').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).attr('title', old_title);
    $('.title-message').html('').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.title-message{
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type= "submit" id="submit" class="title-styled" title= "submit your form">

<span class="title-message"></span>
```

**Other option:**

If you want to use a jQuery plugins, [visit this link](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/).