# how to style pure html title for specific anchor tags or div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the title (not the tool tip) for a link. But I can't get any idea that how to style it.

My code is here. I dont want to style it by adding the pseudo-element and before and after elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">


<body>

<h2>Link Titles</h2>
<p>The title </p>
<a href="#" title="this is the title i want to style">Visit our HTML Tutorial</a>



</body>
</html>
```

How can I style the title that appears when you hover on the anchor tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the style of Title attribute inside the anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag)

Comment: use 'onmouseover' and  'onmouseout'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't style it directly, but you can create the same effect using a pseudoelement.

```css
a[myTitle]:hover {
  position: relative;
}

a[myTitle]:hover:after {
  content: attr(myTitle);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  z-index: 1000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h2>Link Titles</h2>
<p>The title </p>
<a href="#" myTitle="this is the title i want to style">Visit our HTML Tutorial</a>
```