# Jquery get message in red color when hover

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, colors, hover

I am getting a message for expired offers as "Offer Expired" when hovering. For now I get the message as just it is. 
Due to the if condition Im using I do not want the message in every table row.

[image]

I need to get the message in red color. How can I do it?

**jquery**

```
<script>

var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var currentDate = d.getFullYear()  + '-' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

$('tr:not(:first)').hover(    
function() {  
    var enddate = $(this).find('.enddate').text();
    if(currentDate > enddate) {
        $(this).prop('title', "Offer Expired"); 
    }
} ); 
</script>
```

**view**

```
                 <table class="table">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Title</th>
                              <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                              <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                              <th scope="col">Description</th>
                              <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                              <!-- <th scope="col"></th> -->
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($offerList as $info){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()."offer/publicview/?id=".urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($info->offid)); ?> " ><?php echo $info->title; ?></a></td>
                                <td><?php echo $info->startdate; ?></td>
                                <td class="enddate"><?php echo $info->enddate; ?></td>
                                <!-- <td><?php echo $info->enddate; ?></td> -->
                                <td><?php echo $info->discrip; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url()."offer/edit/?id=".urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($info->offid)); ?>">Edit</a>                                              
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**update**

[image]

Comment: you cant change the color of a title attribute as that is decided by the browser. there are plugins such as bootstraps popover or similar that will do the job or even css driven methods that produce similar results to the title attr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the style of the title attribute inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vntj13ws/1/ Will this help?

Comment: @samuellawrentz is it possible to use it with the if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the `title` property dynamically and generate the desired title. Please have a look at the following fiddle. As an example, I'm using the `value` attribute. You can insert your logic there.

```js
var date = 100;
$('a').each(function(){
if($(this).attr('value') > date)
$(this).prop('title', 'Order Expired');
});
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  color: white;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Hello world!" value = 90>
  Hover over me
</a>
<br>
<a  title="Hello world!" value = 110>
  Hover over me
</a>
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this. But the messages are shown in two ways when hover. Is there any way to remove one?

Comment: I have removed `.hover` from Jquery and edited the answer. Is that you wanted?

Comment: I have updated my above image. I think I have to use bootstrap popover or other method.

Answer (score 0):

Add span or any tag to your title element where the title "offer Expired" is comming and make css on that element.
If you have added your title column value in span element then make css like this
span:hover:after {
  color:red
}