# How to make substring of an icon's title property as bold using CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I have an glyphicon icon,which on hover displays a specific title text.
In that hover text,there is a heading along with its description which are stored in the title attribute of the icon tag.
So, I need to make the only the heading part of the title attribute as bold.
How can we achieve this?

Comment: You can't style the native title preview with CSS. but there is a way around.
Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag

Comment: thanks Towkir,will check this