# Is it possible to use a language for which no system font exists in title-attribute tooltips?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I'm developing a website that needs to be able to display LTR and RTL scripts, among the latter also [Syriac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_language), which is not supported by all systems out of the box. So, for Syriac I'm using webfonts, which work fine for "normal" text (i.e. headings, paragraphs, and so on).

One part of the site is implemented using a [virtual keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/) written in JavaScript, which has explanations for what certain keys do in the HTML `title` attribute. The tooltips rendered by the browser for these `title` attributes look like this at the moment:

[image: Screenshot of broken tooltip]

My question is: is there any way (without having to change all the browers' sourcecode and without having to add extra HTML via JavaScript) to have the Syriac webfont be used for those `title`-attribute-based tooltips?

Edit: I'm asking this question specifically to find out if it's possible to make the Syriac writing visible. I'm aware that this *might* be the same problem as trying to style the tooltip in some way. But I'm hoping I'm wrong and somebody knows some solution.

Comment: I'd assume this is not customizable by CSS, and hence would rather choose to display my own tooltips rather than relying on the browser's ones. Why don't you want this alternative exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the style of the title attribute inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag) rationale: @font-face is part of "style".

Comment: I'm aware of that question @Kalido. My hope was, that *just* making the Syriac text visible might be a different case and possible to be made to work. Hence the new question...

Comment: As for your question: I'd like to avoid having to change a project that isn't my own and where politics come into play (the author might not want such self-made tooltips, or I might not understand how to integrate them into his project, etc...

Comment: No if the user doesn't have the font on their system, no way.

Comment: Kalido, that sounds like you're confident about the matter. If you'll make your comment into an answer I'll be very (un)happy to accept that.