# Is It possible to change the background and text colour of a tooltip message without using javascript?

Tags: html, css

```
<span class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip"
                            style="color:white; background-color: orange" 
                            title="captain teemo"></span>
```

It only changes the icon of the tooltip not the message when the mouse cursor hovers on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2011158/9140740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the default tooltip appearance using simple CSS since it is browser/OS-dependent. If you do want to change the appearance of the tooltip I suggest you use javascript or a third party library instead of using the default tooltip generated from your browser/OS.