# Overlapping avatars: convert SCSS to CSS and PUG to HTML

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, pug

I'm trying to create overlapping avatars in HTML and CSS. It is based on this code [snippet.](https://codepen.io/ryanparag/pen/JeROmG) Only that this snippet is created in SCSS and PUG. How can I convert PUG to HTML and SCSS to CSS? I have a problem that the avatars are distant from each other and the name does not appear when you hover over the avatar.

Check code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qzk4eh?file=index.js).

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     todos: 
          [
            {name:'Tobias', avatar: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arresteddevelopment/images/7/77/2x01_The_One_Where_Michael_Leaves_%28098%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20121126025806'},
            {name:'Lindsey', avatar: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arresteddevelopment/images/1/16/Season_3_Character_Promos_-_Lindsay_Bluth_F%C3%BCnke_01.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111027201233'},
            {name:'Buster', avatar: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arresteddevelopment/images/b/be/Season_3_Character_Promos_-_Buster_Bluth_01.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111027201440'},
            {name:'George Michael', avatar: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arresteddevelopment/images/c/c3/Season_1_Character_Promos_-_George_Michael_Bluth_02.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20120429230332'},
            {name:'Gob', avatar: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arresteddevelopment/images/0/02/Season_1_Character_Promos_-_G.O.B.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20120429230530'},
            {name:'Michael', avatar: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arresteddevelopment/images/1/10/1x01_Pilot_%2839%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20120301050056'}
          ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    let todos = this.state.todos.map((todo, index) =>
      <Todo
        key={index}
        index={index}
        todo={todo}

      />
    )
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{todos}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const  Background = this.props.todo.avatar;
    const  name = this.props.todo.name;


const profile = {
    "&:hover&:after": {
      position: "absolute",
      content: `attr(${name})`,
      background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, .95)",
      color: "inherit",
      fontSize: "10px",
      padding: "4px",
      width: "auto",
      bottom: "-0.5rem",
      right: "-0.5rem",
      boxShadow: "0px 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12)",
      opacity: "0",
      borderRadius: "0.15rem",
      animation: "fade 100ms ease 750ms forwards"
    } 
  }

    return (
      <ul className="c-profile__list">
        <li style={profile} className="c-profile" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`}}></li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: system-ui;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #2c2c54;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.c-profile {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(44, 44, 84, .2);
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.c-profile:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  margin-left: -42px;
}
.c-profile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgba(44, 44, 84, .2);
}
.c-profile:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(username);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: auto;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
  right: -0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  animation: fade 100ms ease 750ms forwards;
}
.c-profile__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.c-profile__list:hover .c-profile:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
article {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a short look...

You are wrapping `ul` tags in a parent `ul`. Quick fix:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ctuy4n?file=index.js

Comment: Variable 'profile' doesn't work. I can't set `name`. I can set attribute title={name}. But I can't change background-color tooltip

Answer (score 1):

In your `Todo`, you need to remove the additional `<ul>` tag around each item and add your `name` as a `title` prop:

```
return (
        <li style={profile} className="c-profile" title={name} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`}}></li>
    );
```

Comment: How can I change background-color attribute 'title'?

Comment: It isn't possible with the native title tooltip, you have to use another solution for that. See here for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag

Comment: I tried it. I have variable `profile` and `content: attr(${name})`, 
but I'm probably setting it wrong `"&:hover&:after": ` in my variable `profile`. How set `&:hover&:after` in React?