# How to modify a hyperlink's title css

Tags: html, tags, tooltip, title

I want to modify the title css of a link. Is there a way to do that without using any tooltip? Or is it best to use tooltips?

```css
input[title] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" title="Here is a title" />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this `input[title]{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    color:aqua;
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag